# How do I isolate the amount of a recurring contribution in CiviRules?

Tags: civicontribute, civirules

I want to use CiviRules to add new recurring donors to a group when they sign up, depending on how much they give per month.

I could set up the trigger to look at the value of each new contribution, but that will activate the rule every month.

My thought was to have the rule triggered on new membership (we are using iATS to generate memberships based on recurring contributions), and use the Membership Recurring Contribution field to evaluate the amount, but apparently that is simply an id number.

How can I find the value of a recurring contribution and add users to a group depending on the amount, but only when they first sign up?

CiviCRM 5.24.6, CiviRules 2.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use search builder using condition shown in image to create a smart group.

You can add more filter based on your payment processor to limit the result to first payment, for that you will need to diff between first payment and second payment in civicrm_contribution table. For example if you using paypal for recurring contribution than the first contribution has invoice_id set but the subsequent ones are set to NULL so you can use filter like Invoice reference not null, for Smart debit you can use contribution source eg contribution source like %Membership form%.

[image]

Comment: This would also find $10/mo donors who made a one time $100 donation though.